# What is the right way to pass parameters into callback functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's a working example. As you can see I'm calling `setElemHeight` function with a returned value from `getElemHeight`. But
i think it's a bad practice to pass value instead of function.

**Option 1)** I can wrap it in anonymous function like this:

```js
function () { getElemHeight('.map-svg') }
```

**Option 2)** I can call it inside `setElemHeight` function and pass parameter there, but i think it would ruin  Open Closed Principle.

My question is:  What is the right way to pass parameters into callback functions?

Thanks.

```js
function(elem) {
  return $(elem).height()
}

function setElemHeight(elem, callback, offset) {
  let elemHeight = callback
  $(elem).height(elemHeight - offset)
}
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  setElemHeight('#dealersTabContent', getElemHeight('.map-svg'), 190)
})
```

Comment: This should be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "_it would ruin Open Closed Principle_" How is that? Calling a function in another function has nothing to do with Open Closed Principle ..?

Comment: Option 1 will proceed to retrieve the element height only when the function is invoked. Option 2 will execute the function immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a value to a function is just fine, unless the height of the element changes over time.

If it changes, you'll want to re-calculate the height on each call of the event handler. If it does not, you can just pass the value in, since it will always use the same value anyway.

Also, this line:

```
 let elemHeight = callback
```

If `callback` is a function, this doesn't actually invoke the callback, it just assigns the function to a new variable.
If you want `elemHeight` to get the return value, you'll need to do this instead:

```
 let elemHeight = callback() // <== Notice the parenthesis
```

If it's a value, you probably want to change the name.

As for the Open Closed principle, I think that in JS, being a dynamic, weakly typed language, this will probably mostly apply to modules and not a specific code snippet. There are some tricks for creating encapsulation in JS and for allowing extension only in certain places, but generally you can plug anything you want anywhere, so I just don't worry about it.

Comment: As for the `callback`  argument, I think it's just a bad naming and not the missing parenthesis. `getElemHeight(...)` sounds like it's returning a numeric value and not a function so the `callback` should be renamed to `calculatedHeight` rather than treated as a function that needs to be called. But I might be wrong, it's hard to understand exactly what is OP's concern here.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the two cases OP was talking about are in the code at the same time.

Comment: Regarding callback/missing args - OP doesn't know how to make it a "callback", hence the question.   In addition to this answer (`height=callback()`) OP needs to change the call to `setElemHeight('#dealersTabContent', function () { getElemHeight('.map-svg') }, 190)`

Comment: That's not true, the OP gave the example of "wrapping it in an anonymous function", which would make it a callback. The question was whether to use a callback or a value.

Comment: Funny, I read it as "*What is the right way to pass parameters into callback functions?*" :)  so they want to use a callback, with a parameter

Comment: @freedomn-m I think the title should have been "What is the right way to pass parameters to Event Handlers?", the parameter is to the callback that is given to `on`.

Comment: err?  there's no event handler in OPs `setElemHeight` and not sure what `on` has to do with anything, eg jquery ajax `success:` isn't `onsucess:`.  btw I'm saying your answer is correct (needs `()` - but also needs to pass a function variable, but currently passes function result)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221098/discussion-between-kraylog-and-freedomn-m).